# Having trouble adding liquidity - JSON RPC Error

Tags: pancakeswap, binance-smart-chain

I've been having this error over and over again when trying to get liquidity into my token on Pancakeswap. I've reviewed everything and looks fine to me. Can any of you take a look and guide me on the right direction? At this point I do not know what the issue may be.

Token transfers work just fine, its only when I get to add liquidity that I get this issue.  I would really appreciate any help on this matter

```
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

/*
INHERITANCE CLASSES
*/


abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address payable) {
        return payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes memory) {
        this; 
        return msg.data;
    }
}


library Address {

    function isContract(address account) internal view returns (bool) {
        // According to EIP-1052, 0x0 is the value returned for not-yet created accounts
        // and 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470 is returned
        // for accounts without code, i.e. `keccak256('')`
        bytes32 codehash;
        bytes32 accountHash = 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470;
        // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
        assembly { codehash := extcodehash(account) }
        return (codehash != accountHash && codehash != 0x0);
    }

    function sendValue(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
        require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Address: insufficient balance");

        // solhint-disable-next-line avoid-low-level-calls, avoid-call-value
        (bool success, ) = recipient.call{ value: amount }("");
        require(success, "Address: unable to send value, recipient may have reverted");
    }

    function functionCall(address target, bytes memory data) internal returns (bytes memory) {
      return functionCall(target, data, "Address: low-level call failed");
    }

    function functionCall(address target, bytes memory data, string memory errorMessage) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        return _functionCallWithValue(target, data, 0, errorMessage);
    }

    function functionCallWithValue(address target, bytes memory data, uint256 value) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        return functionCallWithValue(target, data, value, "Address: low-level call with value failed");
    }

    function functionCallWithValue(address target, bytes memory data, uint256 value, string memory errorMessage) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        require(address(this).balance >= value, "Address: insufficient balance for call");
        return _functionCallWithValue(target, data, value, errorMessage);
    }

    function _functionCallWithValue(address target, bytes memory data, uint256 weiValue, string memory errorMessage) private returns (bytes memory) {
        require(isContract(target), "Address: call to non-contract");

        // solhint-disable-next-line avoid-low-level-calls
        (bool success, bytes memory returndata) = target.call{ value: weiValue }(data);
        if (success) {
            return returndata;
        } else {
            // Look for revert reason and bubble it up if present
            if (returndata.length > 0) {
                // The easiest way to bubble the revert reason is using memory via assembly

                // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
                assembly {
                    let returndata_size := mload(returndata)
                    revert(add(32, returndata), returndata_size)
                }
            } else {
                revert(errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}


contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;
    address private _previousOwner;
    uint256 private _lockTime;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    constructor () {
        address msgSender = _msgSender();
        _owner = msgSender;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msgSender);
    }

    function owner() public view returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(_owner == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, newOwner);
        _owner = newOwner;
    }

    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        transferOwnership(address(0));
    }

}


/*
PANCAKESWAP & UNISWAP CLASSES
*/

interface IUniswapV2Factory {
    event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint);

    function feeTo() external view returns (address);
    function feeToSetter() external view returns (address);

    function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external view returns (address pair);
    function allPairs(uint) external view returns (address pair);
    function allPairsLength() external view returns (uint);

    function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair);

    function setFeeTo(address) external;
    function setFeeToSetter(address) external;
}


interface IUniswapV2Pair {
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);

    function name() external pure returns (string memory);
    function symbol() external pure returns (string memory);
    function decimals() external pure returns (uint8);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);

    function approve(address spender, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool);

    function DOMAIN_SEPARATOR() external view returns (bytes32);
    function PERMIT_TYPEHASH() external pure returns (bytes32);
    function nonces(address owner) external view returns (uint);

    function permit(address owner, address spender, uint value, uint deadline, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) external;

    event Mint(address indexed sender, uint amount0, uint amount1);
    event Burn(address indexed sender, uint amount0, uint amount1, address indexed to);
    event Swap(
        address indexed sender,
        uint amount0In,
        uint amount1In,
        uint amount0Out,
        uint amount1Out,
        address indexed to
    );
    event Sync(uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1);

    function MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY() external pure returns (uint);
    function factory() external view returns (address);
    function token0() external view returns (address);
    function token1() external view returns (address);
    function getReserves() external view returns (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1, uint32 blockTimestampLast);
    function price0CumulativeLast() external view returns (uint);
    function price1CumulativeLast() external view returns (uint);
    function kLast() external view returns (uint);

    function mint(address to) external returns (uint liquidity);
    function burn(address to) external returns (uint amount0, uint amount1);
    function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external;
    function skim(address to) external;
    function sync() external;

    function initialize(address, address) external;
}


interface IUniswapV2Router01 {
    function factory() external pure returns (address);
    function WETH() external pure returns (address);

    function addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint amountADesired,
        uint amountBDesired,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity);
    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity);
    function removeLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
    function removeLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
    function removeLiquidityWithPermit(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
    function removeLiquidityETHWithPermit(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapTokensForExactTokens(
        uint amountOut,
        uint amountInMax,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapTokensForExactETH(uint amountOut, uint amountInMax, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapETHForExactTokens(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);

    function quote(uint amountA, uint reserveA, uint reserveB) external pure returns (uint amountB);
    function getAmountOut(uint amountIn, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountOut);
    function getAmountIn(uint amountOut, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountIn);
    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function getAmountsIn(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}


interface IUniswapV2Router02 is IUniswapV2Router01 {
    function removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountETH);
    function removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountETH);

    function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
    function swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable;
    function swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external;
}


contract Token is Context, Ownable {
    using Address for address;

    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;
    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFee;
    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcludedFromLimits;
    mapping (address => bool) private _blacklistedAccount;
    address[] private _excluded;

/*
TOKEN INFO
*/

    uint public _decimals = 18;
    string public _name = "Geoaktif Token";
    string public _symbol = "GETO";
    uint public _totalSupply = 100000000 * 10 ** 18;


    uint256 private liquidityTreshold = 1500;
    uint256 private numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity = liquidityTreshold * 10**18;

    uint public _maxTxAmount = _totalSupply/20; //5% of total supply maximum tx amount
    uint public _maxWalletAmount = _totalSupply/20; //5% of total supply maximum wallet amount

    address payable public taxAddress = payable(0x8820BCaB1Afa1ef5c5E68877068583BAa14E5E54);
    address payable public marketingAddress = payable(0xc52E32301F8Fd233FdC97Cd9ae162018a8503CD1);
    address payable public socialFundingAddress = payable(0x0f817F09216420ebBbC59FEb22106A246488DB45);
    address public contractAddress = address(this);
    

    uint public burnFee = 2; //2%
    uint public taxFee = 2; //2%
    uint public marketingFee = 2; //2%
    uint public LPfee = 0; //0% during presale
    uint public socialFunding = 2; //2%

    uint public previousBurnFee=burnFee;
    uint public previousTaxFee=taxFee;
    uint public previousMarketingFee = marketingFee;
    uint public previousLiquidityFee=LPfee;
    uint public previousSocialFunding = socialFunding;
   
    IUniswapV2Router02 public immutable uniswapV2Router;
    address public immutable uniswapV2Pair;
    
    bool inSwapAndLiquify;
    bool public swapAndLiquifyEnabled = true;
    
    event MinTokensBeforeSwapUpdated(uint256 minTokensBeforeSwap);
    event SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(bool enabled);
    event SwapAndLiquify(
        uint256 tokensSwapped,
        uint256 ethReceived,
        uint256 tokensIntoLiqudity
    );
    
    modifier lockTheSwap {
        inSwapAndLiquify = true;
        _;
        inSwapAndLiquify = false;
    }


    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);

    constructor() {
        //10% Team
        //2.5% Marketing
        //2.5% Social Funding
        //85% Liquidity
        balances[0x0f6E02F6a6a3F1548Fe7F49559614d88e4359494] = _totalSupply*85/100; //owner wallet
        balances[marketingAddress] = _totalSupply*25/1000; //Marketing
        balances[socialFundingAddress] = _totalSupply*25/1000; //Social Funding
        balances[taxAddress] = _totalSupply*10/100; //Team


        IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E); 
        //0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E mainnet
        //0x9Ac64Cc6e4415144C455BD8E4837Fea55603e5c3 testnet

        _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[contractAddress] = true;

        _isExcludedFromLimits[owner()] = true;
        _isExcludedFromLimits[contractAddress] = true;

         // Create a uniswap pair for this new token
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())
            .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());

        // set the rest of the contract variables
        uniswapV2Router = _uniswapV2Router;

        _isExcludedFromLimits[uniswapV2Pair] = true;
        

        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
    }


/*
LIQUIDIY POOL 
*/

    // -------> PancakeSwap functions
    receive() external payable {} 

    function swapAndLiquify(uint256 contractTokenBalance) private lockTheSwap {
        // split the contract balance into halves
        uint256 half = contractTokenBalance/2;
        uint256 otherHalf = contractTokenBalance-half;

        uint256 initialBalance = address(this).balance;
        swapTokensForEth(half);
        uint256 newBalance = address(this).balance-initialBalance;
        addLiquidity(otherHalf, newBalance);
        
        emit SwapAndLiquify(half, newBalance, otherHalf);
    }

    function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();

        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0,
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    function addLiquidity(uint256 tokenAmount, uint256 ethAmount) private {
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);

        uniswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: ethAmount}(
            address(this),
            tokenAmount,
            0, 
            0, 
            owner(),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }
    function setSwapAndLiquifyEnabled(bool _enabled) public onlyOwner {
        swapAndLiquifyEnabled = _enabled;
        emit SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(_enabled);
    }

    // <------- PancakeSwap functions



/*
GENERAL FUNCTIONS
*/



    function name() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public view returns (uint) {
        return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address value) public view returns(uint256) {
        return balances[value];
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function contractBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return balances[address(this)];
    }

    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) private {
        require(owner != address(0), "approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

    function totalFees() public view returns (uint256) {
        return burnFee+LPfee+taxFee+marketingFee+socialFunding;
    }



/*
TRANSFER FUNCTIONS
*/


    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }


    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        require(_allowances[sender][_msgSender()]-amount <= amount, "transfer amount exceeds allowance");
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()]-amount);
        return true;
    }


    function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) private {
        require(from != address(0), "transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "transfer to the zero address");
        require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");
        require(balanceOf(from) >= amount, 'balance too low');
        require(_blacklistedAccount[from] != true, "Account is blacklisted");


        if(_isExcludedFromLimits[from] == false) {
            require(amount <= _maxTxAmount, "Transfer amount exceeds the maxTxAmount.");
        }

        if(_isExcludedFromLimits[to] == false) {
            require(balanceOf(to) + amount <=  _maxWalletAmount, 'Transfer amount exceeds the maxWalletAmount.');
        }

        // is the token balance of this contract address over the min number of
        // tokens that we need to initiate a swap + liquidity lock?
        // also, don't get caught in a circular liquidity event.
        // also, don't swap & liquify if sender is uniswap pair.
        uint256 contractTokenBalance = balanceOf(address(this));
        
        if(contractTokenBalance >= _maxTxAmount)
        {
            contractTokenBalance = _maxTxAmount;
        }
        
        bool overMinTokenBalance = contractTokenBalance >= numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
        if (
            overMinTokenBalance &&
            !inSwapAndLiquify &&
            from != uniswapV2Pair &&
            swapAndLiquifyEnabled
        ) {
            contractTokenBalance = numTokensSellToAddToLiquidity;
            //add liquidity
            swapAndLiquify(contractTokenBalance);
        }
        
        //indicates if fee should be deducted from transfer
        bool takeFee = true;
        
        //if any account belongs to _isExcludedFromFee account then remove the fee
        if(_isExcludedFromFee[from] || _isExcludedFromFee[to]){
            takeFee = false;
        }
        //transfer amount, it will take tax, burn, liquidity fee
        _tokenTransfer(from,to,amount,takeFee);
    }


    //this method is responsible for taking all fee, if takeFee is true
    function _tokenTransfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount,bool takeFee) private {

        uint256 taxAmount;
        uint256 burnAmount;
        uint256 liquidityAmount;
        uint256 marketingAmount;
        uint256 socialFundingAmount;

        if(!takeFee) {

            taxAmount = 0;
            burnAmount = 0;
            liquidityAmount = 0;
            marketingAmount = 0;
            socialFundingAmount = 0;

            balances[sender]-=(amount);
            balances[recipient]+=(amount);

            emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        }

        else {

            taxAmount = calculateTaxFee(amount);
            burnAmount = calculateBurnFee(amount);
            liquidityAmount = calculateLiquidityFee(amount);
            marketingAmount = calculateMarketingFee(amount);
            socialFundingAmount = calculateSocialFundingFee(amount);


            balances[sender]-=(amount);

            balances[taxAddress]+=(taxAmount);
            balances[marketingAddress]+=(marketingAmount);
            balances[socialFundingAddress]+=(socialFundingAmount);
            balances[address(this)]+=(liquidityAmount);
            _totalSupply-=(burnAmount);

            balances[recipient]+=(amount-taxAmount-burnAmount-liquidityAmount-socialFundingAmount-marketingAmount);

            emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        }   
    }
    


/*
CALCULATE FEES 
*/

    function calculateTaxFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
        return _amount*(taxFee)/(100);
    }

    function calculateLiquidityFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
        return _amount*(LPfee)/(100);
    }

    function calculateBurnFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256) {
        return _amount*(burnFee)/(100);
    }

    function calculateMarketingFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256){
        return _amount*(marketingFee)/(100);
    }

    function calculateSocialFundingFee(uint256 _amount) private view returns (uint256){
        return _amount*(socialFunding)/(100);
    }


/*
INCLUDE AND EXCLUDE FROM FEES FUNCTIONS
*/

    function excludeFromFee(address account) public onlyOwner {
        _isExcludedFromFee[account] = true;
    }
    
    function includeInFee(address account) public onlyOwner {
        _isExcludedFromFee[account] = false;
    }

    function isExcludedFromFee(address account) public view returns(bool) {
        return _isExcludedFromFee[account];
    }
    
    function excludeFromLimits(address account) public onlyOwner {
        _isExcludedFromLimits[account] = true;
    }
    
    function includeInLimits(address account) public onlyOwner {
        _isExcludedFromLimits[account] = false;
    }

    function isExcludedFromLimits(address account) public view returns(bool) {
        return _isExcludedFromLimits[account];
    } 

    function blacklistWallet(address wallet) external onlyOwner() {
        _blacklistedAccount[wallet] = true;
    }

    function removeFromBlacklistWallet(address wallet) external onlyOwner() {
        _blacklistedAccount[wallet] = false;
    }

    function isBlacklisted(address wallet) public view returns(bool){
        return _blacklistedAccount[wallet];
    }


/*
ONLYOWNER EDIT CONTRACT FUNCTIONS
*/

    function setTaxAddress(address _taxAddress) external onlyOwner() {
        taxAddress = payable(_taxAddress);
    }

    function setMarketingAddress(address _marketingAddress) external onlyOwner() {
        marketingAddress = payable(_marketingAddress);
    }

    function setSocialFundingAddress(address _socialFundingAddress) external onlyOwner() {
        socialFundingAddress = payable(_socialFundingAddress);
    }


    function setMaxTransaction(uint256 _maxTransaction) external onlyOwner(){
        _maxTxAmount = _maxTransaction;
    }

    function setMaxWallet(uint256 _maxWallet) external onlyOwner(){
        _maxWalletAmount = _maxWallet;
    }


    function manualBurn(uint256 _amount) external onlyOwner() {
        balances[msg.sender] -=_amount;
        _totalSupply -=_amount;
    }

    function changeLiquidityTreshold(uint256 _number) external onlyOwner(){
        liquidityTreshold = _number;
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you add the exact error message to the question?

Answer (score 0):

try to set: `bool public swapAndLiquifyEnabled = false;`